# Can not open clipboard access in denied on copying a text from skype

Tags: skype

I'm getting this alert error when trying to copy text from my Skype:

```
Cannot open clipboard: Access is denied
```

What could be the issue?.Even CTRL-c and CTRL-V and not working.

Comment: Because there's no obvious sign of it, I have to ask: Is this at all code related? If it is, you really should post what code you're using. Otherwise it's just guesses, and we don't like to *guess* here. That's not constructive.

Comment: No its not code related . I'm simply using it on Windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: Then it's off topic for Stack Overflow, a Q&A site about programming questions. Try [su].